# Can't get props from Redux Connect() in React Router 4 nested route

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-redux, react-router-v4

I'm trying to access props from Redux connect() in my nested route. But can't get it work..

I have the following components:

main.js
    const initState = {};

```
const history = createBrowserHistory();
const store = configureStore(initState, history);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <App />
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

In app.js I set up few routes

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/auth" component={Auth} />
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      </Switch>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(App);
```

Then in Auth component

```
function Auth(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Route exact path={`${props.match.path}/login`} component={Login} />
    </div>
  );
}
export default withRouter(Auth);
```

And finally my Login component

```
export class Login extends Component {
  login({email, password}) {
    this.props.login({ email, password });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Form
        onSubmit={(credentials) => this.login(credentials)} />
    );
  }
}

Login.propTypes = {
  login: PropTypes.func
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    login: (credentials) => dispatch(loginRequest(credentials))
  };
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Login);
```

Triggering `this.props.login({ email, password });` should dispatch my `loginRequest(credentials)` actions.

However I get a `this.props.login is not a function` error. Actually no props is set in my Login component..`connect()` seems to have not effect at all.

The parents have access to props injected by `connect()`, however this 2nd level route, can't get the props that it's supposed to receive..

I hope it's clear enough.. Am I missing something ? Any idea about what could go wrong ?

Thanks for any help !

Comment: Is your login function has a proper this binding? [link](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56)

Comment: @KamilSocha the login function received all the props not depending of the connect that's why I could'nt understand it.. But Shubham-khatri pointed out the mistake of the 2 exports in my login component.. Would have take me sometime to realize it without a second pair of eyes !
Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `export` while defining the logic class from `export class Login extends Component {`  and make sure you are importing logic as a default component like `import Login from '/path/to/Login`

```
class Login extends Component {
  login({email, password}) {
    this.props.login({ email, password });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Form
        onSubmit={(credentials) => this.login(credentials)} />
    );
  }
}

Login.propTypes = {
  login: PropTypes.func
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    login: (credentials) => dispatch(loginRequest(credentials))
  };
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Login);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! That was it !
Still trying to figure out if I was totally blind or not.. It would have take me sometime to figure it out without another pair of eyes ! Thank for your help @shubham-khatri